# Data Annotations on derived classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a number of partial views that deal with different derived classes of Foo.

Each derived class has a number of properties exclusive to that class.

The properties in the base class , Foo, all contain data annotations, such as Required, Range, etc.  Unfortunately these don't seem to be triggering when I have a strongly typed view using a derived class.

It simply allows me to post the form with incorrect data.  What is the best strategy for dealing with this?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you overriding base properties in the derived class?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, I'm not overriding base properties.  Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It appears that it's not the inheritance causing the problem, but the fact I am now using partial views...

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference - I have the same case in one of my projects and have no problems with the validation attributes

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've just created a new question specifically for this issue, with some code example.  Thanks.